# How to remove frontend spaces | Unix shell script |

Tags: shell-script

I am not getting a command, how to remove frontend spaces from below data after I make use of `uniq -i -c` command

**Explanation :**
if you look at the data below you can see their is 2 tab spaces available
that I want to get rid of it

**Note :** [*Output is shared below*]

**Data in file :**

```
     2 00
     2 01
     2 00
     2 02
     1 03
     3 aa
```

**Output :**

```
2 00
2 01
2 00
2 02
1 03
3 aa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe your data into `sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//'`, which removes all leading characters from the class `[:blank:]`, which is the space and tab character, or locale dependent equivalent characters.

Using `sed`, we apply the regular expression `^[[:blank:]]*` on the data to transform it into nothing (as there is nothing in between the two last slash characters. In the regular expression, `^` stands for the start of the line and `*` for matching as many of the preceding class as possible, so we are matching as many as possible `[:blank:]` characters from start as possible.

Comment: will you be able to tell without using `[[ : blank : ]]` , how this command is also giving me the same Output as expected :  `sed 's/^ *//' Test.txt`

Comment: The command you supplied removes all leading ` ` (<space>) characters, but stops on encountering a tab character or other locale dependent blank characters. As I was unsure about whether the lines start with a tab character, I choose `[[:blank:]]`. But if your lines are preceded by only spaces, that command is certainly fine.

Comment: Thanks Pim for the explanation