# How to print a table from a Nawk file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm trying to print information from a file formatted as table.
I have so far

```
BEGIN {
    OFS = "\t";
    FS = ":";
    print "\t\t----Employee Information---- ";
    printf("%s %40s %20s %4s %8s %4s %15s \n", "NAME", "TELEPHONE", "AGE", "|", "Salary", "|", "License No.")
}
{ printf ("%s %30s %30s %30s %30s\n", $4, $1, $5, $2, $3) }
```

It takes care of the columns but I can't seem to be able to arrange the data how I wish.

Here's a sample of the data I have to output:

```
{246} 548-1278:2500:175A106:Miss Cherise Hilton-Moore : 30
{408} 538-2358:1550:201B154:Mr Reynold Watson :37
{210} 655-6279:2600:509UYT6:Miss Natalie Judy-Sealy :32
{210} 548-1348:2500:175XCVD3:Mr John McCollin : 26
{208} 548-1278:1880:150P9URE:Mr Ronald Francis: 31
```

In order there's area code, phone number, salary, License Number, Name, Age.
I wish to arrange it under the columns:

```
Name       Telephone        Age       Salary      License Number.
```

But the output I get looks as follows:

```
NAME                                TELEPHONE                  AGE    |   Salary    |     License No.
Miss Cherise Hilton-Moore                  {246} 548-1278  30                           2500                        175A106
Mr Reynold Watson                  {408} 538-2358  37                           1550                        201B154
Miss Natalie Judy-Sealy                  {210} 655-6279  32                           2600                        509UYT6
```

EDIT:
First off, thanks to everyone for their guidance. This is what I have so far:

```
BEGIN {FS = ":";
print "\t\t----Employee Information---- ";
printf("%s %40s %20s %4s %8s %4s %15s \n", "NAME", "TELEPHONE", "AGE", "|", "Salary", "|", "License No.")}\
{printf ("%-35s %-26s %-10s %-15s %-10s\n", $4, $1, $5, $2, $3)}

#End of Script
```

It wouldn't say it works in the general case. I'll continue to look but, this was based on my understanding of specifiers.

Comment: do you have `column` command installed?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add i) an example of your input file and ii) the output you would like to get from that example. We can't help you parse data you don't show.

Comment: How do you want to "_arrange the data how I wish_?

Comment: @αғsнιη the column command isn't available

Comment: Your first `%s` has no width formatting, so the corresponding string value is simply printed _as is_ without regard to subsequent columns. Also, notice that your heading widths don't correspond to your data widths

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. I took your advice and specified a minimum with a left justification

Comment: @Malcolm     may be this reference will help you https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621898/script-for-formatting-code-into-columns/621900#621900   ... just with minor change you can print the desired output ...try to run this command   `sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//' File.txt | column -t -s ":"`  as data is coming between colon  `:`  so i given field separator as colon  ... if want more better solution go through the above reference and try every command shared by every user

Comment: @codeholic24 thanks for the reference but I am trying to do this with a nawk file script.

Comment: Thank you all! I beginning to understand and will post my own solution in a little while.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    ARGV[ARGC] = ARGV[ARGC-1]   # So we can read the input twice, first to get the max field widths.
    ARGC++

    # Not using character class [:blank:] because nawk does not support character classes
    FS = "[ \t]*:[ \t]*"

    split("TELEPHONE:SALARY:LICENSE NO.:NAME:AGE",inNr2Name)
    for (inNr in inNr2Name) {
        name = inNr2Name[inNr]
        wid  = length(name)
        name2wid[name] = wid
        f[name] = inNr                  # field name to input field number
    }

    print "\t\t----Employee Information---- "
}
NR==FNR {
    for (inNr=1; inNr<=NF; inNr++) {
        name = inNr2Name[inNr]
        val  = $inNr
        wid  = length(val)
        name2wid[name] = (name2wid[name] > wid ? name2wid[name] : wid)
    }
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    outFmt = "%-" name2wid["NAME"]      "s "    \
             "%-" name2wid["TELEPHONE"] "s "    \
             "%-" name2wid["AGE"]       "s "    \
             "| "                               \
             "%-" name2wid["SALARY"]    "s "    \
             "| "                               \
             "%-" name2wid["LICENSE NO."] "s\n"

    printf outFmt, "NAME", "TELEPHONE", "AGE", "SALARY", "LICENSE NO."
}
{
    printf outFmt, $(f["NAME"]), $(f["TELEPHONE"]), $(f["AGE"]), $(f["SALARY"]), $(f["LICENSE NO."])
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
                ----Employee Information----
NAME                      TELEPHONE      AGE | SALARY | LICENSE NO.
Miss Cherise Hilton-Moore {246} 548-1278 30  | 2500   | 175A106
Mr Reynold Watson         {408} 538-2358 37  | 1550   | 201B154
Miss Natalie Judy-Sealy   {210} 655-6279 32  | 2600   | 509UYT6
Mr John McCollin          {210} 548-1348 26  | 2500   | 175XCVD3
Mr Ronald Francis         {208} 548-1278 31  | 1880   | 150P9URE
```

I used lots of intermediate variables, all with meaningful names, so I expect you'll be able to understand what it does after a bit of thought and looking at man pages but if not then feel free to post questions.